# I get an error trying to import the rcdb tutorial json data to MongoDB via Compass

Tags: mongodb, autodesk-forge

I am trying to import JSON data into MongoDB via Compass and I get this error

```
    Unexpected token ":" (0x3A) in JSON at position 10 while parsing near " \"_id\" : ObjectId(\"57efaead..." in C:\Users\Michael.Pares\source\repos\forge-rcdb.nodejs\resources\db\rcdb.models.json

> 1 | "_id" : ObjectId("57efaead77c8eb0a560ef465"),
| ^
2 | "name" : "Car Seat",
3 | "env" : "Local",
4 | "layout" : {
```

Here is what the JSON looks like

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57efaead77c8eb0a560ef465"),
"name" : "Car Seat",
"env" : "Local",
"layout" : {
    "type" : "flexLayoutRight",
    "rightFlex" : 0.35
},
"model" : {
    "urn" : "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bGVlZnNtcC1mb3JnZS9zZWF0LmR3Zg",
    "path": "https://sbhehe.github.io/sb233/carseat/0.svf",
    "name" : "Car Seat"
},
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use the option `ADD DATA > Insert Document` to certify that your schema is correct.[image]
For that, you won't need `ObjectId` to pass the id of the document.
The JSON below is in the proper format.

```
{
  "_id": "57efaead77c8eb0a560ef465",
  "name": "Car Seat",
  "env": "Local",
  "layout":{
    "type": "flexLayoutRight",
    "rightFlex": 0.35    
  },
  "model":{
    "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bGVlZnNtcC1mb3JnZS9zZWF0LmR3Zg",
    "path": "https://sbhehe.github.io/sb233/carseat/0.svf",
    "name": "Car Seat"    
  }
}
```

If you compare it with the one you have (with [textcompare](https://text-compare.com)) you can see that is also missing one `}` at the end of your JSON.